# HTML5 Boillerplate IE Conditional IE8 Explanation

Tags: html

I have been looking for an explanation of why this part of the html tag conditionals for IE in the HTML5 Boilerplate have this part:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

I ask just so I have an understanding of how this is working. I understand the conditionals above this one, but why is this one different than those above it? I don't get what this condition is doing compared to those above it.

Thank you in advance for helping me to understand something that I will be using.

Comment: I read about this somewhere, I think it used to be in the docs before they apparently moved them to github. Basically they chose a more confusing syntax that took advantage of some oddity since it was a few characters shorter than what would be need for if they used a `!IE` clause, I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the last part is used for IE versions 9 and up, and all other browsers. However, the syntax is shorter and not as straight-forward as it could be because HTML Boilerplate is heavily concerned with optimization.

I found the article that explains it, I recommend you read the whole thing:

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

> Here's my proposed solution:
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
> ```

This was actually updated afterwards due to issues you can read about in the article.

Apparently part of the weird syntax has to do with a Dreamweaver(!) bug. Here is an excerpt:

> Here is the new recommendation, and the one that's in use in the HTML5
>   Boilerplate.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Basically, the last line is saying "Do this if IE9+ or not IE". Some of the bullet points below are not directly related to your question, but I'll include them anyways.

> Why?
>
> - This fixes a file blocking issue discovered by Stoyan Stefanov and
>     Markus Leptien.
> - It avoids an empty comment that also fixes the above
>     issue.
> - CMSes like WordPress and Drupal use the body class more
>     heavily.
> - This makes integrating there a touch simpler It doesn't
>     validate in html4 but is fine in html5. Deal with it.
> - It plays nicely
>     with a technique to kick off your page-specific javascript based on
>     your markup.
> - It uses the same element as Modernizr (and Dojo). That
>     feels nice.
> - I left an empty class in there because you'll probably be
>     putting a no-js in there or something else. If not, delete.
> - **Also if
>     the extra comments around that last tag look weird to you, blame
>     Dreamweaver, which chokes on normal !IE conditional comments.**

More discussion about this issue here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/425/#

Comment: I'm not certain this directly addresses your question, let me know if there's something specific I can explain in more detail - it's a good idea to read that article plus read up on conditional comments in general - wikipedia has a good page on them.

Comment: Could not have asked for a better explanation to clear this up for me and make me comfortable in knowing why I would be using it. The answers for the newest recommendations help me very much. Thank you